# Return focus at the end of the text at text area after closing jQuery colorbox

Tags: jquery

This is bugging me. I have an application that launches jQuery colorbox and then insert content to the text area editor then it closes with this line:

```
$.colorbox.close();
```

The problem is that I could not return the focus or mouse cursor to blink at the end of the inserted content. How to do this in jQuery? I would like to add this code after closing the colorbox. But I could not figure out. Thanks for the help.

It is a Wordpress Text editor that can be selected with:

```
$('#content')
```

I have tried this after colorbox close:

```
$('#content').focus();
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to add to your colorbox onClosed event (replace #content with the ID of your text area:

```
                onClosed: function() {

                    //Assign focus after inserting content

                    var content_inserted = $("#content").val();
                    $("#content").focus().val("").val(content_inserted);

                    }
```

Take note I simply cannot rely on:

```
$('#content').focus();
```

Even inside the onCLosed event since it does not put the cursor at the end of the inserted text on other browsers like Chromium or Chrome. I need to reset the text area content under focused first then insert it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for that

```
function moveCaretToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ghAB9/6/

Comment: Thanks Michael. But this is not working for me. I have found out how to do this. See my answer to my own question>

Comment: I have posted my own answer.. This is working for me...Cheers.